# how to filter a dynamic parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way I can filter a dynamic parameter before it prompts?
For example if I have:

```
**current data:**    
    cust table
    cust a
    cust b
    cust aa
    cust bb
    cust cc
    cust dd
    cust aaa
```

I want my parameter to prompt on all cust that starts `cust a`

```
**results**
cust a
cust aa
cust aaa
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate command just for the dynamic parameter.

Comment: could you please post and example? @Lan

Comment: I am not sure I understand .... You are not asking me to create a sample report, right ? You need to create a command inside your report and link the dynamic parameter to the command instead of the to the report

Comment: I am asking you to post a sample code of the command. I am not sure what you are talking about. Could you please guide me with some steps?

Comment: Here is a tutorial how to create a command in Crystal reports: http://www.hexcentral.com/articles/crystal-sql-commands.htm